# Show that the sequence $\left\{\frac{2n}{2n-1}\right\}$ is monotone by using $a_{n+1} - a_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Note: I am looking at the sequence itself, not the sequence of partial sums.

Here's my attempt...

Setting up:

$$\left\{\frac{2(n+1)}{2(n+1)-1}\right\} - \left\{\frac{2n}{2n-1}\right\}$$

Simplifying:

$$\left\{\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}\right\} - \left\{\frac{2n}{2n-1}\right\}$$

$$\frac{(2n+2)(2n-1)-(2n)(2n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}$$

$$\frac{4n^2+2n-2-(4n+2n)}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}$$

$$\frac{4n^2-4n-2}{4n^2-1}$$

How should I proceed from this point? I think I need to get rid of the ratio, so that I can judge whether or not it'll be positive or negative. Or can I just judge from this point that it will be a positive value? When I use the $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ test, I get a result that the sequence is strictly decreasing.

Comment: Do you mean you want to prove the sequence of partial sums is monotone?

Comment: Or that the sequence itself is?

Comment: @HBeel The sequence, not the sequence of partial sums. Sorry, Should've specified. I'll edit that.

Comment: Do the curly brackets mean ["fractional part"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to know that the numerator and denominator are both negative.

To do that, fix the error in algebra:
\begin{align}
& \frac{(2n+2)(2n-1)-(2n)(2n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n-1)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{4n^2+2n-2-(4n^2+2n)}{(2n+1)(2n-1)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{-2}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}
\end{align}

Comment: I figured it was some silly mistake like that... Got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n=\frac{2n}{2n-1}=1+\frac1{2n-1}\implies$$

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac1{2n+1}-\frac1{2n-1}=-\frac2{(2n-1)(2n+1)}<0$$

and thus the sequence is monote descending.

Comment: How does $\frac{2n}{2n-1}=1+\frac1{2n-1}$ ?

Comment: @Keenan Do the math!

Comment: That helps me so much.

Comment: @Keenan, how does it not? $a\pm\frac{b}{c}=\frac{ac\pm b}{c}$ where $c\not = 0$. Surely you've seen this before seeing sequences...

Comment: @k170 Now that helped me. I actually had not. And saying "Do the math!" literally says nothing.

Comment: @Keenan To someone **really** aspiring to be a serious chemistry student, that should say a lot: check the expression, try to play with it, modify it (mathematicwise, of course), common denominator, etc. After all, chemistry is a *science* and you're going to need analytic capabilities. That particular expression is junior-high's level, and it is understandable you forgot it, but not so much that you will give up at once to try to work it out and instead ask for the solution.

Comment: That's a fair criticism.